# How to globally disable PEP 495 warnings?

Tags: python, configuration, warnings

Many Python programs I use spit out this warning:

```
PytzUsageWarning: The localize method is no longer necessary, as this time zonesupports the fold attribute (PEP 495). For more details on migrating to a PEP 495-compliant implementation, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
  localized_events = self.get_localized(localize(start), localize(end))
```

I assume the idea here was to emit the warning every time, so that the developer would soon see it and update his code. This appears to have been too optimistic, as many developers do not swiftly update their software, nor do I have the time to comb through their code and fix it myself.

I couldn't care less about this particular warning, not even in my code. But it constantly pollutes my STDOUT since it turns out I use many Python programs and many of them use Pytz. How can I make Python not emit `PytzUsageWarning`, ever?

Answer (score 0):

Add this comment at the end of the line

```py
# noqa
```

NOQA stands for No Quality Assurance. It tells the interpreter/compiler/code analysis software to ignore warnings

Comment: I want to disable only `PytzUsageWarning`, not other warnings. Also, I don't want to add a line to every single Python program on my computer.